# Queria saber como criar variáveis através de for em javascript?

Tags: javascript, otimização

pois estou criando uma pagina com javascript que tem muita variaves que muda apenas como no trecho abaixo

```
  var divClearFloat1 = document.createElement("DIV");
  var divClearFloat2 = document.createElement("DIV");
  var divClearFloat3 = document.createElement("DIV");
  var divClearFloat4 = document.createElement("DIV");
  var divClearFloat5 = document.createElement("DIV");
  var divClearFloat6 = document.createElement("DIV");
  var divClearFloat7 = document.createElement("DIV");
```

Comment: Não sei te dizer se está é a melhor abordagem em javascript, mas pra uma noção de algoritmos mesmo, seria melhor você fazer um array ou uma lista e preencher as posições dela.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que vais fazer com esse código?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para este tipo de coisas, existem os *arrays*, que são uma coleção indexada de dados.

Em vez de fazer `variavel1`, `variavel2`, você usa uma variável só, e um índice de qual dos dados armazenados dentro dela se refere (`variavel[1]`).

Para inicializar um *array* já com dados:

```
var lista = [
   1,
   2,
   3
];

var nomes = [
   'Zé',
   'Maria',
   'Chico'
];
```

Como no seu caso você vai usar um *loop*, pode começar com um array vazio, epara acrescentar um dado novo em um *array* sem apagar ou sobreescrever os anteriores, o JS tem o método `push`:

```
lista = [];
lista.push(30);
lista.push(12);
lista.push(53);

// lista passou a ser [30, 12, 53]
```

Veja um exemplo bem simples da criação de 10 informações independentes usando *array*:

```js
var lista = []; // aqui criamos um array vazio de nome "lista"
var i;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  // troque o i * i pelo que quiser armazenar
  // por exemplo, push( document.createElement( ... ) );

  lista.push( i * i ); 
}

document.body.innerHTML += "O valor de lista[5] é " + lista[5];
```

No seu caso, basta fazer isto na linha do `push`

```
lista.push( document.createElement("DIV") );
```

E para usar qualquer ítem, basta por o índice entre os colchetes:

```
lista[5].innerText = 'Cinco';
```